# Why was this grammar edit rejected?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I am trying to figure out where I went wrong with this edit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/16911846

I cleaned up quite a few grammar issues, and it was rejected by two users because

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Very few of my attempts to improve English readability have been straight up declined. So I can learn and improve, can someone point out what is different in this one?

Comment: Apart from leaving in the "Please help." - doesn't look an unreasonable edit...

Comment: Your edit does improve the post, but imo you could have done a little more. The language is still poor and you should remove the "please help" bit completely.

Comment: I'm not sure why that question is left open. I still can't make sense of it even after your edit.

Comment: @BilltheLizard well - some weird PHP... some SQL words and some names... isn't it obvious what the solution is or does your Psychic Debugging Crystal Ball need charging? :p

Comment: @JonClements I want this result: `PHP code` But I get this error: `SQL code` table: `bulleted list` I don't know what's what anymore.

Comment: @BilltheLizard so they follow the yellow brick road where the great Oz will provide the answer... simples really, no? :p

Comment: Ok, that's not SQL code. I literally do not know what is what.

Comment: I suspect it got rejected because the edit doesn't stop the question from being unclear. Don't edits dispute flags already on a post or am I remembering that incorrectly?

Comment: @BSMP Certain types of flags, yes (like VLQ).   Not all (not even all non-moderator flags, if memory serves).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm glad you're paying attention to the reviews and trying to learn from them. I remember the frustration of having to go through edit reviews. Some of my rejections I didn't agree with, but overall they helped me improve my editing. Once you hit 2000 rep points, you can edit instantly without review.

As an example of imperfect reviewers, I recently rejected what looked like a strange edit and then when I looked back at it, I realized that the editor was simply inserting information gleaned from comments with the OP. So then, I wished I hadn't rejected it. No one is perfect.

Comment: I'd argue that the editor should have made that clear in their edit summary but yes, sometimes the reviewer can make a mistake.

Answer (score -2):

There will always be users who will inquire about their edit suggestions. There are edits that can be easily approved because they make a clear and substantial improvement. But whether edits like yours are important or not is left to the appreciation of the reviewing community. In general, it is better to avoid inquiring about them here. Anyway a good and useful edit is most likely to be appreciated and approved by the community.

More importantly, it is better not to edit the grammar and/or spelling of closed questions, if they would still merit closure after your edit, because, in case your edit is approved, that will create more work for the reviewing community as it makes the question candidate to the ***Reopen Votes*** queue.

Comment: *More importantly, it is better not to edit the grammar and/or spelling of closed questions* This is true but, FWIW, the question hadn't been put on hold when the edit was made.

Comment: I wasn't trying to complain here. I don't frequently have a problem with rejected edits, but this one baffled me so I was looking for insight I didn't have. I think I've gotten it from your answer and the comments on the question itself. Thank you.

Comment: *Inquire* is the word I would go with :)

Comment: " In general, it is better to avoid inquiring about them here"? Why? Edit already rejected and asking about it not going to change that much. If user willing to listen to most likely negative feedback and not burst into "you #@#@ don't get my capitalization of 'Sir' change" rage  (rarely the case) asking on meta is absolutely correct thing to do... Also reading existing questions may be safe option.

Comment: Also, questions only get **one** chance in the reopen queue, so if you fix the grammar without moving the question back on-topic, it will be very difficult to get the question reopened, because the reviewers will review as “Leave Closed,” wasting the question’s chance at reopening.